# Extracting substring based on a single or double digit character using javascript

Tags: javascript, string, substring

This is a new question based on my previously asked question [Extracting substring from string based on delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45918849/extracting-substring-from-string-based-on-delimiter) (answer accepted)

I have a string `]d1[)½}06~9N110375286414~1T12345ABCD~D150600~S12345ABCDEF98765}`

**Note**: There is a space after `}` in the above example

My delimiters on the above strings are 9N, 1T, D, S and I need to extract the substrings after the delimiter until it hits `~` or EOL.

In the fiddle below it is expecting `D1` and `S1` as the delimiters instead of `D` and `S` respectively.

**I am facing 2 problems**

1) Single char delimiter issue (`D`, `S`)

2) How should I strip off `}` at the end of the string when returning values. For example, the substring with delimiter `S` should return `12345ABCDEF98765` instead of `12345ABCDEF98765}`

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ty067z0c/3/) (Results are console based)

JS

```
// Use ]d1[)½}06~9N110375286414~1T12345ABCD~D150600~S12345ABCDEF98765} 
// Note: There is an empty space after the } char as shown above

var dataNames = {
  '9N': 'PPN',
  '1T': 'batchNumber',
  'D': 'expireDate',
  'S': 'serialNumber'
};

var input = document.querySelector("input");
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var str = input.value;
  console.log(parseGS1(str));
});

function parseGS1(str) {
  var fnc1 = "~";
  var data = {};

  //remove ]d1[)½}06~
  str = str.slice(10);

  while (str.length) {
    //get the AI identifier: 1T, 9N etc
    let aiIdent = str.slice(0, 2);
    //get the name we want to use for the data object
    let dataName = dataNames[aiIdent];
    //update the string
    str = str.slice(2);

    switch (aiIdent) {
      case "1T":
      case "9N":
        let fnc1Index = str.indexOf(fnc1);
        //eol or fnc1 cases
        if (fnc1Index == -1) {
          data[dataName] = str.slice(0);
          str = "";
        } else {
          data[dataName] = str.slice(0, fnc1Index);
          str = str.slice(fnc1Index + 1);
        }
        break;
      case "D":
      case "S":

        //eol or fnc1 cases

        break;
      default:
        console.log("unexpected ident encountered:", aiIdent);
        return false;
        break;
    }
  }
  return data;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also do this using a regex. With this solution it will still work when parts of the string are moved around.

```js
function getData(input) {
  input = input.slice(0, input.length - 2);
  // The regex has two capture groups. 
  // Group 1 gets the identifier, this can also be the start of the string.
  // Group 2 gets all the characters between the identifier and the '~' char or '} '.
  // The third group is a non-capturing group, it is used to find the delimiter where the next part starts.
  var
      regex = /(^|9N|1T|D|S)(.*?)(?:~|$)/g,
      data = {},
      match = regex.exec(input);

  while (match !== null) {
    switch(match[1]) {
    case '9N':
      data.PPN = match[2];
      break;
    case '1T':
      data.batch = match[2];  
      break;
    case 'D':
      data.expireDate = match[2];  
      break;
    case 'S':
      data.serial = match[2];  
      break;  
    }
    var msg = 'Found ' + match[0] + ' / identifier = ' + match[1]  +  ' / value = ' + match[2] + '. ';
    console.log(msg);

    // Get the next match.
    match = regex.exec(input);
  }
  return data;
}

var input = ']d1[)½}06~9N110375286414~1T12345ABCD~D150600~S12345ABCDEF98765} ',
    input2 = ']d1[)½}06~9N110375286414~D150600~1T12345ABCD~S12345ABCDEF98765} ';
console.log(getData(input));
console.log(getData(input2));
```

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there any way I can always skip the last 2 chars. In my given example it is `} ` but, I would like to skip the last 2 chars always.

Comment: `input = input.slice(0, input.length - 2);`

Comment: and I keep the regex as it is?

Comment: When you remove the last the chars, the regex also needs to be changed. I've updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: why do we still need to have `} ` in the regex when we are slicing off the input?

Comment: ...and it's gone... (didn't update that part of the regex).

Answer (score 0):

If your string always has the format you show in the question, you could split the string at the ~ symbol and then only check the first 2 characters of the substrings.

```
var string = "]d1[)½}06~9N110375286414~1T12345ABCD~D150600~S12345ABCDEF98765} "

var substrings = string.split('~');
substrings.shift(); //get rid of irrelevant first array element
substrings[substrings.length-1] = substrings[substrings.length-1].replace("} ", "");
```

The replace in the above exmaple eliminates the curly brace at the end. But I'm not entirely sure if that's the most elegant way. It is for sure not the most flexible, so if you face anything other than curly brace + space at the end, it would not be removed of course.

After extracting these substrings and getting rid of the very first array element, you can then concentrate on only checking the first characters in your string.

Answer (score 0):

In your example `~` is at the end of the substring, and it is also at the start of a delimiter.

Therefore you can use `~` as part of the delimiter itself and use `~9N`, `~1T` etc in a regular expression to split up the string. This solves the problem with single char delimiters as `D` and `S` now become `~D` and `~S`.

Second issue is solved by matching on `}` in the regular expression and eliminating it from the output by not capturing it as part of the substring following `~S`.

Sample code:

```js
// your input
var str = ']d1[)½}06~9N110375286414~1T12345ABCD~D150600~S12345ABCDEF98765} ';

// regex to parse delimiters
var pattern = /(.*)~9N(.*)~1T(.*)~D(.*)~S(.*)\}/;

// delimiter descriptions
var dataNames = {
  '9N': 'PPN',
  '1T': 'batchNumber',
  'D': 'expireDate',
  'S': 'serialNumber'
};

// test input
console.log(parseGS1(str));

// parse function
function parseGS1(str) {
  // call regex
  var match = pattern.exec(str); // try console.log(match);

  // output object
  var data = {};
  
  // match items 2-5 should be substrings
  data[dataNames['9N']] = match[2];
  data[dataNames['1T']] = match[3];
  data[dataNames['D']] = match[4];
  data[dataNames['S']] = match[5];
  
  return data;
}
```

Comment: the problem here is the regex won't work if I switch the sequence. for e.g if put 9N delimiter at the end instead of S delimiter.

Comment: @zaq have a look at my solution, it uses a regex but doesn't have this issue.

Comment: @Thijs yes, your solution works. I just wanted to report it in this comment so that Robin could make the answer even better and universal.